# Add custom field automatically with category URL

Tags: php, wordpress

I've found some code to add a custom field automatically to each new post:

```
add_action('publish_page', 'add_custom_field_automatically');
add_action('publish_post', 'add_custom_field_automatically');
function add_custom_field_automatically($post_ID) {
    global $wpdb;
    if(!wp_is_post_revision($post_ID)) {
        add_post_meta($post_ID, 'cat', '' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '', true);
    }
}
```

I have put this code into my `functions.php` file, and it halfway works. It auto-adds a new custom field, but how do I echo the value being the posts category slug?

As the custom form will only be added once published, we would have already selected a category for it. So can we echo this?

```
add_action('publish_page', 'add_custom_field_automatically');
add_action('publish_post', 'add_custom_field_automatically');
function add_custom_field_automatically($post_ID) {
    global $wpdb;
    if(!wp_is_post_revision($post_ID)) {
        add_post_meta($post_ID, 'cat', 'CATEGORY LINK HERE', true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the ID of the post:

```
echo get_post_meta($post_ID, 'cat', true);
```

I'm curious, where are you trying to echo this?